# Stable Wake-On-LAN PCI-e card for Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wakeonlan

I would like to be able to wake up my PC computer over internet. 
I am trying to find some stable Wake-On-LAN card for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
I have a sufficient TP-link router TL-WR1043ND 2nd version where I can make sufficient bridge/connection to the computer for Wake-On-LAN.

Possibilities

- TP-Link TG-3468 but has Realtek RTL8168B chip
- Intel 9301CT with processor Intel 82574L
- ...

I really like TP-Link hardware generally but I am unaware how it competes with Intel in Wake-On-LAN cards and in Ubuntu.

---

How can you choose a stable Wake-On-LAN PCI-e card for Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought *Intel 9301CT* but not succeeded in setting it up because I thought more expensive would be better. I am troubleshooting the thing [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/749583/25388). I will provide here later my experiences about the product.

System: Ubuntu 16.04